# Sublime Text 2: Copy file on save / backup to another folder

Tags: rsync, sublimetext, sublimetext2

In i.e. Adobe Dreamweaver it's possible to set up automatic copying of saved files to another project specific location. How can I achieve this with Sublime Text 2?

I'm on Windows 7 and I don't want to install third-party tools (like rsync for Windows) to watch a folder and then take action on a change. I just want to save my file to two locations (local SVN repository and a second windows remote share folder).

Is there a plugin which does this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is now a plugin suitable for my needs: [SublimeFileSync](https://github.com/bcharbonnier/SublimeFileSync)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does the sync work? For example, does it only sync files that are changed on the source folder? What if files at the destination are changed?  Will they get overwritten?  The reason I ask is that I'll be using it to copy files from the project source folder (under version control) across to the web server.  The web server copy will have numerous generated files (e.g. images, log files etc) which i don't want removed since the project source is clean / doesn't have any of these generated files...

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [Automatic Backup Plugin](https://github.com/joelpt/sublimetext-automatic-backups). It doesn't backup the files at a project-specific location, but it is a good way to automatically save a backup every time you save a file.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not (yet) possible to read the relative directory path of the project, so I cannot rewrite the plugin code to save a copy of a file to the right location.

I have now set up a FTP server on my testing location and I use the [Sublime SFTP plugin](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/akalongman/sublimetext-autobackups

Configuration options:

```
{
    // Don't make changes to this file directly as they can get wiped out when the
    // plugin is updated. Instead transfer what you need to the 'Settings - User' file.

    // The directory where we'll keep our backups. If empty, we'll try to put them in
    // ~/sublime_backups
    "backup_dir": "~/sublime_backups",

    // If true, also save a backup copy any time a file is opened (if backup file not exists)
    "backup_on_open_file": true,

    // If true, backups saved per day, in separate folders, for example ~/sublime_backups/2013-05-23/myfile.php
    "backup_per_day": true,

    // If set, backups saved per second. possible values: false, "folder" or "file"
    // false - disabled backup per second
    // "folder" - backup example D:/Sublime Text Backups/2013-05-23/095034/myfile.php
    // "file" - backup example D:/Sublime Text Backups/2013-05-23/myfile_095034.php
    // to use this feature, you must have enabled backup_per_day setting
    "backup_per_time": "file",

    // Files larger than this many bytes won't be backed up.
    "max_backup_file_size_bytes": 262144, // = 256 KB

    // Files older than X days will be deleted. If 0 - auto delete disabled
    "delete_old_backups": 0, // days to delete

    // If true, backup file opened in same line as cursor in original file
    "open_in_same_line": true,

    // If true, show backup previews (only in ST3)
    "show_previews": true

}
```